# access jupyterhub on docker from external network

Tags: docker, jupyter, jupyterhub

Docker is fairly new to me, I'm creating a jupyterhub container like that

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

# install nodejs, utf8 locale, set CDN because default httpredir is unreliable
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y update && \
apt-get -y upgrade && \
apt-get -y install wget git bzip2 && \
apt-get purge && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# install Python + NodeJS with conda
RUN wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh  && \
echo 'e1045ee415162f944b6aebfe560b8fee */tmp/miniconda.sh' | md5sum -c - && \
bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -f -b -p /opt/conda && \
/opt/conda/bin/conda install --yes -c conda-forge \
  python=3.6 sqlalchemy tornado jinja2 traitlets requests pip pycurl \
  nodejs configurable-http-proxy && \
/opt/conda/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH

ADD . /src/jupyterhub
WORKDIR /src/jupyterhub

RUN npm install -g configurable-http-proxy
RUN python3 -m pip install jupyterhub
RUN python3 -m pip install dockerspawner 

WORKDIR /srv/jupyterhub/
EXPOSE 8000

COPY jupyterhub_config.py /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py

LABEL org.jupyter.service="jupyterhub"

CMD ["jupyterhub"]
```

with the following configuration file, base on [this discussion](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/187)

```
# launch with docker
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'dockerspawner.DockerSpawner'

# we need the hub to listen on all ips when it is in a container
c.JupyterHub.hub_ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.JupyterHub.port = 8000
c.DockerSpawner.extra_host_config = {'network_mode': 'host'}
c.DockerSpawner.use_internal_ip = True
c.DockerSpawner.network_name = 'host'
```

Then I do:

`docker run -i -p 8000:8000 --name jupyterhub jupyterhub:latest jupyterhub -f jupyterhub_config.py`

It works as expected on my internal network, but I can't access it externally. If I do:

`my_ip:8000`

I can't connect.

For my Flask apps running on docker, all I do is to run the app in a `0.0.0.0` ip and it works, I'm confused here on how to configure the network. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I built an image with your Dockerfile and it seems to work: `firefox http://localhost:8000` properly displays the Jupyter login.

Comment: Question: are you already aware of the official image https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyterhub/jupyterhub ? which is documented in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/docs/source/troubleshooting.md#jupyterhub-docker-container-not-accessible-at-localhost (BTW I am not 100% sure if `-f jupyterhub_config.py` is really necessary in your CLI example)

Comment: Finally here is another useful link: https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/networking-basics.html

Comment: thank you for your comments @ErikMD, yes I'm aware of the oficial image, but I need to customize it, and it also works on my local host. I want to deploy it and access from another computer, there is where I'm confused with the network configuration. And finally, I have seen the last link and tried all configurations for ip and port, still can't access from another computer, while for my flask apps on docker I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after struggling for a while I found a solution, based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1716) and the documentation [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config-proxy.html). My `jupyterhub_config.py` became:

```
c.JupyterHub.bind_url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/jhub'
```

and following the links I provided the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/jupyterhub.conf` became

```
# top-level http config for websocket headers
# If Upgrade is defined, Connection = upgrade
# If Upgrade is empty, Connection = close
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name my_ip;

  location /jhub {
      rewrite /jhub/(.*) /jhub/$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # websocket headers
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
     allow all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure nginx on localhost, witch will proxy requests from external world for port that will listen to local port with your expose in your docker container

```
server {

    server_name <your_ip>;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
    listen 7000; 
}
```

now you can open `<your_ip>:7000` from external

Comment: Thank you @Ryabchenko, that can work, but really wanted to understand how to configure docker.